# How to make JSONarray null in android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, pull-to-refresh

I am building an android application where there is an Home screen in which onCreate I am Initializing the Async task. In that Async task I fetch data from server and show using baseAdapter.

Now the problem is while Refreshing I fire the Async task again And it duplicate my data So, I need is to make the old data delete and the new data insert in list using BaseAdapter.

Here is make Async task -

```
 /**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class questionfeed_async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ServiceHandler http = new ServiceHandler();
        jsonString = http.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET,
                null);
        if (jsonString != null) {
            try {
                SCROLL_TO_POSITION = currentQuestionArray.length();
                questions = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                //result_text = new String[questions.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                    temp_obj = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    JSONObject currentQuestionObject = new JSONObject();

                    currentQuestionObject.put("question_text", temp_obj.getString(Tag_questionText)
                            .toString());

                    currentQuestionArray.put(currentQuestionObject);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Empty");
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


            adapter = new BaseAdapterFeed(getActivity(), currentQuestionArray);

            questionfeed_customelistview.setAdapter(adapter);               

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // probably don't bother doing clean up
        } finally {
            // carry on as if nothing went wrong
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in "currentQuestionArray".You have to create new everytime. Like `currentQuestionArray=new HashMap<String,String>()` in your doInBackground method.The problem is everytime  a new currentQuestionObject is inserted in the map but the old is also remaining. Hope it helps you.

Comment: THanks for replying but this will not help me as it will become problem in pagination. So I have make this array empty will Refreshing

Comment: can you suggest a way in which I clear the old JSONArray and again initialize while Refreshing. and then fire my Async task

Comment: All I know is -----Just create a new JSONArray.

JSONArray otherJsonArray = new JSONArray();
Or iterate through the array and remove(int index) the indexes.

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#remove(int)

Answer (score 0):

Create new adapter during refresh, also new array as mentioned above

Comment: THanks it's dose not a good idea to make new baseadapter and new array, can you suggest other way to make old data delete and store load new.